# Database of HQ, tech giants, healthcare industries moving their workforce to Miami, FL

Tags: finance, real-estate, technology

Looking for large corporations or highly valued ones that are planning to or have already moved their HQ to Miami, FL from various locations in the US or abroad.

Perspective- Developing a marketing strategy that will generate leads for buyers or tenants considering living in Miami. Currently, I have two properties I am the listing agent representative, and given the influx of migrants moving to Florida from California or Los Angeles, I'm hoping to tap into their interest either rent or sell my current listings, or help them find the right place for them. I am a two-year involved agent and am gaining knowledge in the luxury market by coincidence. Trying to tap into this sphere of influence remotely.